# getting error in JavaFX Text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

i have created this small project for my academics, it was being developed and working correctly until i added **Text field** in it. I'm new JavaFx so i have created it while learning from youtube...help will be appreciated.

1.Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

2.Controller.java

```
package sample;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Controller{
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextArea TextArea;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar MenuBar;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem createFile;

    @FXML
    private Text Text;







    @FXML
   void editSaveAs()
    {
Text.setValue("helo w");
       /* FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter =
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(selectedFile != null){
            SaveFile(TextArea.getText(), selectedFile);

        }*/

    }
    @FXML
    void editOpen()
    {
      File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

      if (selectedFile!=null)
      {
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getPath());

          try{
              FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(selectedFile);
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
              String s ;
              String f="" ;
              while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
              {

                  f=f+s+"\n";


              }
              TextArea.setText(f);
              bufferedReader.close();
          }catch(Exception error)
          {
              System.out.println(error);
          }

      }
    }
    private void SaveFile(String content, File file){
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter;

            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(content);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }


    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert Text != null : "fx:id=\"text\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample.fxml'.";
        assert TextArea != null : "fx:id=\"TextArea\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'textEditor.fxml'.";
        assert MenuBar != null : "fx:id=\"MenuBar\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'textEditor.fxml'.";


    }
}
```

3.sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="499.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <MenuBar fx:id="MenuBar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New          (Ctrl+N)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editOpen" text="Open       (Ctrl+O)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save          (Ctrl+N)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editSaveAs" text="Save As...    " />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo          (Ctrl+Z)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut             (Ctrl+X)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy          (Ctrl+C)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste          (Ctrl+V)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete        (Del)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Find...         (Ctrl+F)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Replace...   (Ctrl+H)" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All     (Ctrl+A)" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Font Size">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action">
                            <graphic>
                                <ScrollBar orientation="VERTICAL" />
                            </graphic>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
        <TextArea fx:id="TextArea" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="51.0" />
      <Text id="Text" layoutY="48.0" text="sd" wrappingWidth="99.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This all are my files from ide....

and i get following **error** after adding **Text** in it.

```
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -javaagent:/home/shubham/Downloads/idea-IU-181.5281.24/lib/idea_rt.jar=37607:/home/shubham/Downloads/idea-IU-181.5281.24/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/shubham/IdeaProjects/FirstJavaFx/out/production/FirstJavaFx sample.Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.editSaveAs(Controller.java:45)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Please explain exactly how it doesn't work. Any specific test scenario, and error messages, etc.

Comment: @jingx i have created menulist in which first option is edit...in edit option there are many options including "save as"..so for save as menu i have created onAction="#editSaveAs" ... and in controller.java  i have created editSave() function.  when i click on save as menu... my "Text" should have to set.